# python find the gap between numbers

Tags: python

Every second, the number can move up or down by 1 and this comes from api.

Let's say the number started from 0 and it reached up to 100.
Then when it gradually decreased down to 50, I'd stop the program.

So whenever the number increased first from any starting number and it peaked at certain number then later found it decreased -50 like the above example (100-50 = 50) I have to stop it. I tried to implement this in code, but need some help.

```
starting_number = self.api.get_current_number()
current_peak_number = 0
count = 0
has_initially_increased = False

While True:
    current_number = self.api.get_current_number()

    if has_initially_increased is False:
        if current_number > starting_number:
            current_peak_number = current_number
            has_initially_increased = True
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        if current_peak_number <= current_number:
            current_peak_number = current_number
        else:
            gap = current_peak - current_number
            if gap == 50:
                break

    count += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

I find this can be improved or corrected.

Comment: What is your question? Is there a specific problem with this code?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @sanyash Not with the current description, absolutely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few issues with your code:

1. `has_initially_increased` is never set to `True` in the else branch (first if/else level). Since `has_initially_increased` is initialised to `False`, the code block in the if statement will never be be executed at all.
2. If you fix the first point, if `current_number` is lower than `starting_number`, this will terminate the loop, but this doesn't mean your conditions are met (reached a given peak and then decreased to the floor value of 50). So why a break here?
3. The other condition for a break is the difference between the highest peak and the current value to be 50, but there is no check that you met expected peak.

Finally, what is the purpose of your `count` variable? This doesn't seem to be used at all.